# Jquery buscar input que contenham texto especifico

Tags: jquery

Qual seletor `jquery` que utilizo para buscar todos os inputs que contenham texto especifico, por exemplo tenho vários `checkbox` com textos diferentes, ai digito CA e ele busca todos os `checkbox` com texto que contenha CA, depois disso vou exibir somente esses e esconder os outros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal é que seus checkboxes tenham um value igual ao texto que você quer buscar.

Assim você pode utilizar as queries jQuery

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][value*='Teste']")
```

Por exemplo

Repare no operador ***=** da query, isso é o mesmo que "contains" ou seja ele procura em qualquer parte da sua string. Caso queria que seja exatamente o mesmo texto, utilize **=**.

Exemplo no findler: https://jsfiddle.net/aLusvy63/

**Editado**

Para o caso de utilizar o data-text ficaria

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][data-text*='texto']")
```

Mais informações sobre seletores jQuery em https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: legal, no lugar de colocar o texto igual o id, posso usar um atributo data ? exemplo data-texto="CA" ? se sim, como ficaria?

Comment: @henriquedpereira veja minha edição da resposta.

Comment: muito bom, isso que queria, vlw.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
$(":checkbox").filter(function() {
  return this.value == '5';
}).prop("checked","true");
```

ou

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value=5]").prop("checked",true);​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/59hHK/30/